# Plotly stacked barchart - not correct colors in legend

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

I'm trying to plot stacked bar chart in `plotly (plotly_4.5.6)` from data like here:

```
> dane
visit_source variable value
1      organic     2016    32
2       social     2016    20
3           hp     2016    24
4      branded     2016    24
5      organic     2015    25
6       social     2015    25
7           hp     2015    25
8      branded     2015    25
```

Using this code:

```
library("dplyr")
library("plotly")

plot_ly(dane, y = ~variable, x = ~value, color = ~visit_source, text = ~paste0(value, "%"),
        type = "bar", hoverinfo = "text+name", marker = list(line = list(color = "white", width = 2))) %>%
    layout(barmode = "stack",
           legend = list(orientation = "h"),
           xaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"),
           yaxis = list(title = ""))
```

I get:

[image]

But when I modify my `data.frame` a bit (only get rid of one row), some colors in legend become black. Like here:

```
plot_ly(dane[-1, ], y = ~variable, x = ~value, color = ~visit_source, text = ~paste0(value, "%"),
        type = "bar", hoverinfo = "text+name", marker = list(line = list(color = "white", width = 2))) %>%
    layout(barmode = "stack",
           legend = list(orientation = "h"),
           xaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"),
           yaxis = list(title = ""))
```

[image]

When I have all `levels` of `visit_source` for each `year` with `value` equal `0`, then it works, but also appear in `hover`, which I do not like.

Do you know what is the problem here? Thanks for any help!

My data:

```
structure(list(visit_source = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                          2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("organic", "social", "hp", "branded"), class = "factor"), 
               variable = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", 
                            "2015", "2015"), value = c(32, 20, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25
                            )), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("visit_source", "variable", 
                                                                 "value"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)) -> dane
```

Comment: Something funky is going on since `dane[c(-1, -5), ]` yields an OK result (missing one level). If you make a ggplot and use `ggplotly`, it will produce an OK result.

Comment: Might be a bug. As @RomanLuštrik mentions, if you completely drop the level 'organic' it produces correct results...

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest developer version of `Plotly` (4.5.6.9000) and it should work

[image]

```
df = data.frame(visit_source=c('organic', 'social', 'hp', 'branded', 'organic', 'social', 'hp', 'branded'), 
                variable = c(rep('2016', 4), rep('2015',4)),
                value=c(32, 20, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25))


library("dplyr")
library("plotly")

plot_ly(df[-1,], y = ~variable, x = ~value, color = ~visit_source, text = ~paste0(value, "%"),
        type = "bar", hoverinfo = "text+name", marker = list(line = list(color = "white", width = 2))) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack",
         legend = list(orientation = "h"),
         xaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"),
         yaxis = list(title = ""))
```